# Sql server 2008 conexão

Tags: sql-server

Boa noite

Instalei o Microsoft SQl Server Management Studio 2008 na minha máquina para fazer testes locais, porém não consigo fazer o acesso. 
Mesmo sendo gratuito, como posso instanciar o acesso, terei que reinstalar o banco?
Segue erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Veja se você não instalou apenas o Management Studio. Garanta que também instalou o Server.

- Verifique se na instalação, você utilizou por instancia ou no Default.
- Verifique se o serviço foi iniciado:

[image: Imagem da janela de serviços]

Caso não tenha instalado o Serviço do SQL (LocalDB), você pode utilizar os passos neste link:[Como instalar o SQL Server 2008 (Instalação](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms143219(v=sql.100).aspx)

Comment: não encontrei o serviço. E não me recordo se foi por instância ou Default. 
Neste caso, como devo proceder, seria melhor reinstalar o programa?

Comment: Então provavelmente você instalou apenas o Studio e não instalou o LocalDB (que é o servidor local). Aqui você pode baixar a versão mais recente do SQL Server Express (LocalDB) https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express . Você terá que executar uma nova instalação.

Comment: Entao preciso reinstalar o Sql server 2008 e depois LocalDB?

Comment: Achei um passo a passo com imagens : http://wiki.websolute.com.br/Como_Instalar_o_Microsoft_SQL_Server_2008_Express_Edition_em_uma_VPS%3F  . Você precisa instalar o servidor local e não apenas o Studio.